# SAR value in ASUS Zenfone 5

Tags: dialer-codes, asus-zenfone-5

When I type `*#07#` into the dialer on my Asus Zenfone 5, it is not showing the SAR value. This works on other phones. How can I get the SAR value on an Asus Zenfone 5?

Answer (score 1):

The box of my Asus Zenfone 5 (501CG) says

SAR (some chinese characters) 2.0 W/Kg; (some chinese characters again):0.710 W/Kg

Answer (score 0):

Open this link: http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_5-5952.php

Check the SAR level in the "MISC" heading.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

SAR US  1.18 W/kg (head)
SAR EU  0.53 W/kg (head)

http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_5-5952.php#

Answer (score 0):

I got this info from Asus directly. You can input `*#*#4636#*#*` then tap "Phone info", it will show the signal strength.

The reference value is between -50 to -80. If the signal strength is close to -50, the lower the radiation. If the signal strength is close to -80, the signal radiation is stronger.